# Elasticsearch aggregation for each unit python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want for each unit (`org_name_en`) add a new field with aggregation for `review_count` - `sum / count`. Field `members` is a type of `nested`. Below you can see piece of ES db:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "some_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "some_id",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "target_date" : "some_data",
          "org_name" : "abc",
          "org_name_en" : "ABC",
           [...]
          "members" : [
            {
              [...]
              "review_count" : 50.0,
            },
            {
              [...]
              "review_count" : 60.0,
            },
```

Final result should be like:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        [...]
        "_source" : {
          "target_date" : "filtered with some data",
          "org_name" : "abc",
          "org_name_en" : "ABC",
           [...]
          "members" : [
            {
              [...]
              "review_count" : 50.0,
            },
            {
              [...]
              "review_count" : 60.0,
            },
          ],
          "review_total": {
                "review_sum": 110,
                "review_count: 2
           },
         [...next unit DEF, GHI, XYZ with the same aggregation...]
```

My try with **Elasticsearch-DSL** in python - works only for given unit, so I need to filter it out first

```
qs.aggs.bucket('members', 'nested', path='members').metric('review_total', 'sum', field='members.review_count')
```